# Just trying to read the filename with Regex but looks like the one which i wrote is not wokring

Tags: regex

Need help with reading the filename.csv  `KL_Report_CIDataFeed_Extract1_2020-09-09-17-10-34.csv` using regex pattern.

I am trying it with `FileMatcherRegex=[0-9a-zA-Z_]*\.csv`, but this is not reading the above mentioned pattern.

SO quick help is appreciated.

Comment: What language You are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `[0-9a-zA-Z_-]*\.csv` you are looking for.
I added one hyphen -

Answer (score 1):

This may help

```
 Regex Expression:  [\w-]*\.csv
```